# copy text after a specific string from a file and append to another in perl

Tags: perl, copy, append

I want to extract the desired information from a file and append it into another. the first file consists of some lines as the header without a specific pattern and just ends with the "END OF HEADER" string. I wrote the following code for find the matching line for end of the header:

```
$find = "END OF HEADER";                     
open FILEHANDLE, $filename_path;      
while (<FILEHANDLE>) {

     my $line = $_;                                                
     if ($line =~ /$find/) {

         #??? what shall I do here???                                                                                      
     }
}
```

, but I don't know how can I get the rest of the file and append it to the other file.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if the content of the file isn't enormous you can just load the whole file in a scalar and just split it with the "END OF HEADER" then print the output of the right side of the split in the new file (appending)

```
open READHANDLE, 'readfile.txt' or die $!;
my $content = do { local $/; <READHANDLE> };
close READHANDLE;

my (undef,$restcontent) = split(/END OF HEADER/,$content);

open WRITEHANDLE, '>>writefile.txt' or die $!;
print WRITEHANDLE $restcontent;
close WRITEHANDLE;
```

Comment: You should use the three-argument-version of `open` and lexical filehandles like `open my $filehandle , '<' , 'readfile.txt' or die $!;`.

Comment: I agree it would be better, but for this answer I preferred to stay closer to how the original code was written.

Answer (score 1):

This code will take the filenames from the command line, print all files up to `END OF HEADER` from the first file, followed by all lines from the second file. Note that the output is sent to STDOUT so you will have to redirect the output, like this:

```
perl program.pl headfile.txt mainfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

**Update** Now modified to print all of the first file *after* the line `END OF HEADER` followed by all of the second file

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($header_file, $main_file) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '<', $header_file or die $!;
my $print;
while (<$fh>) {
  print if $print;
  $print ||= /END OF HEADER/;
}

open $fh, '<', $main_file or die $!;
print while <$fh>;
```

Comment: there is a missundersranding, I don't want the header from the first file, I just want all except the header (after that string)

Comment: I think I understand. I have modified my answer: does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;

my @lines = read_file('readfile.txt');

while ( my $line = shift @lines) {
  next unless ($line =~ m/END OF HEADER/);
  last;
}

append_file('writefile.txt', @lines);
```

Comment: it seems that this code is correct too, but I encounter a compilation error: 
Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib.); I copied the Slurp.pm in the following directions but it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, I just noticed you are on windows. You can use the package manager for your Perl distribution or cpan/cpanm to pull the file from CPAN. Please Google how to do this if you don't already know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do what you need:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $find = 'END OF HEADER';
my $fileContents;

{
    local $/;
    open my $fh_read, '<', 'theFile.txt' or die $!;
    $fileContents = <$fh_read>;
}

my ($restOfFile) = $fileContents =~ /$find(.+)/s;

open my $fh_write, '>>', 'theFileToAppend.txt' or die $!;

print $fh_write $restOfFile;

close $fh_write;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $status = 0;
my $find = "END OF HEADER";

open my $fh_write, '>', $file_write
    or die "Can't open file $file_write $!";

open my $fh_read, '<', $file_read
    or die "Can't open file $file_read $!";

LINE:
while (my $line = <$fh_read>) {

     if ($line =~ /$find/) {

         $status = 1;
         next LINE;
     }                       

     print $fh_write $line if $status;
}

close $fh_read;
close $fh_write;
```

Comment: Isn't that just going to print 'END OF HEADER" to the file once and nothing else?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, I ran it, but it just write the "END OF HEADER" in the destination file.

Comment: No, I want to copy the rest of the file after the "END OF HEADER" string and append it to another file.

Comment: @maryamyousefi you could use that code and when $line =~ /$find/, set a flag and print to the outfile once that flag is set.

Comment: @jmcneirney I don't know how to set the flag, I have never done this, could you help me and explain it in more details or with an example?

Comment: Your new program includes the `END OF HEADER` line in the output. I doubt if that is what's wanted.

Comment: @maryamyousefi Set a variable before 'next LINE if not $line =~ /$find/. When that evaluates to true, set that variable to 1 or some true value. Then print to the file handle only when that variable (flag) is true. You'll also need to check if the flag is set before running the 'next' line to though.